# Three.js UV map weird

Tags: three.js, blender

I create simple box object with UV map in Blender, and then export it to Three.js JSON, but on render it shows some weird mapping, its like mapping inside the box, not outside..!

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1zwfFhX2lbYQS1PeUgtQ2RjVXM/edit?usp=sharing

JSON code is:`{

```
"metadata" :
{
    "formatVersion" : 3.1,
    "generatedBy"   : "Blender 2.7 Exporter",
    "vertices"      : 8,
    "faces"         : 6,
    "normals"       : 8,
    "colors"        : 0,
    "uvs"           : [22],
    "materials"     : 1,
    "morphTargets"  : 0,
    "bones"         : 0
},

"scale" : 1.000000,

"materials" : [ {
    "DbgColor" : 15658734,
    "DbgIndex" : 0,
    "DbgName" : "Material",
    "blending" : "NormalBlending",
    "colorAmbient" : [0.6400000190734865, 0.6400000190734865, 0.6400000190734865],
    "colorDiffuse" : [0.6400000190734865, 0.6400000190734865, 0.6400000190734865],
    "colorEmissive" : [0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    "colorSpecular" : [0.5, 0.5, 0.5],
    "depthTest" : true,
    "depthWrite" : true,
    "mapDiffuse" : "cube.001.png",
    "mapDiffuseWrap" : ["repeat", "repeat"],
    "shading" : "Lambert",
    "specularCoef" : 50,
    "transparency" : 1.0,
    "transparent" : false,
    "vertexColors" : false
}],

"vertices" : [1,0.2,-1,1,0.2,1,-1,0.2,1,-0.999999,0.2,-1,1,-0.2,-1,0.999999,-0.2,1,-1,-0.2,1,-1,-0.2,-1],

"morphTargets" : [],

"normals" : [-0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,-0.577349,-0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,-0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,0.577349,0.577349,0.577349,0.577349,0.577349,0.577349,-0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,-0.577349],

"colors" : [],

"uvs" : [[0.498471,0,0.5,0.498471,0.001529,0.5,0,0.001529,1,0.001529,0.998471,0.5,0.501529,0,0.601224,0.500306,0.700918,0.5,0.702447,0.998471,0.602753,0.998777,0.80367,0.500306,0.903365,0.5,0.904894,0.998471,0.8052,0.998776,0.599694,0.998777,0.5,0.998471,0.501529,0.5,0.80367,0.998471,0.703976,0.998777,0.702447,0.500306,0.802141,0.5]],

"faces" : [43,0,1,2,3,0,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,43,4,7,6,5,0,4,5,1,6,4,5,6,7,43,0,4,5,1,0,7,8,9,10,0,4,7,1,43,1,5,6,2,0,11,12,13,14,1,7,6,2,43,2,6,7,3,0,15,16,17,7,2,6,5,3,43,4,0,3,7,0,18,19,20,21,4,0,3,5],

"bones" : [],

"skinIndices" : [],

"skinWeights" : [],
```

"animations" : []

}`

Comment: Try to "Flip Normals" in Blender before exporting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a few things going on here.

I think you have some sort of lambert lighting going on, (brightness around one vertex) and no representation of UVs.

Your faces are flipped and are facing the wrong way. The normals are also averaged between your points, hence the reason for the box shading more like a blob than a solid angular object. You can see that from the numbers, box normals should have values like (0,0,1) (1,0,0)  since your box is aligned with xyz (first two verts tell this). Your normals have (.57,.57,.57) which should be a unit vector, main cube diagonal - average of your three faces.

You need to look for an option in your three.js exporter, or you can use the same options you used to get this, but manually flip the faces in blender. Without a live example, it's hard to tell exactly what is going on, because one possible scenario can be that your faces are facing the right way, but the normals are flipped which would cause an additional issue.